# How to Set to Auto resize Jasper Report when display size change

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I use a jasper report as my dashboard when login to the ***Jasper Server 6.4.2*** version.
The problem is how to create a report that auto resize to full size of the dashboard?

On ***Jaspersoft Studio 6.6.0*** version, under **Page Format** window, we can't set auto size. Either from the report source code we can't set the ***pageWidth="1519" pageHeight="1006"*** to auto reset for full size like ***pageWidth="100%" pageHeight="100%"***

How to create report to auto resize according to display sizes like bootstrap responsive design?

I want to make my jasper report size dynamic according to display size.
at-least, Can anyone tell me how to edit jasper server code for this?
I tried to edit jasper server theme using ***pageSpecific.css*** file and tried to set ***#reportContainer*** div size using ***vh,vw*** units.div size changed.but report size still didn't changed. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry to say that, but I don't think you can have dynamic page size in Jasper reports.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But I have to find a way however.